# cakephp 3.0 how to populate a select field with values instead of id

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i was looking for a previous answer, but the ones i've found are related to older cakephp versions

i have two tables, 'magazines' and 'issues' where there is a relation  'issues' BelongsTo 'magazines', this is what IssuesTable looks like:

```
public function initialize(array $config){

$this->belongsTo('Magazines', [
    'foreignKey' => 'id'
]);
}
```

table magazines has two fields, magazines.id and magazines.name

table issues has two fields, issues.id, issues.magazine_id where issues.magazine_id is the foreign key

to populate a select input in the issues view with the magazine.name values and save the issues.magazine_id, i've set the controller like this

```
$this->set('magazines', $this->Issue->Magazine->find('list'));
```

then i've added the following code to the issue view add.cpt

```
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('name', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => false,
    'options' => $magazines, 
    'empty' => true]);
    ?>
```

but i get the input select with the issues.magazine_id as values instead of magazines.name

thanks for your help and comments

Comment: You want to find Issues with for a concrete magazine, am i right?

Comment: no, i want to select a concrete magazine from an input select, where the values are the magazine name but it stores the id. I can not find how to pupulate the input select with the magazine_name instead of the id

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use `find('list')` as this will return the primary key and display field:-

```
$this->set(
    'magazines', 
    $this->Issues->Magazines->find('list')
);
```

Then in your form you need the input name to be `magazine_id` if you're wanting to set the foreign key for the association:-

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'magazine_id', 
    [
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => false,
        'options' => $magazines, 
        'empty' => true
    ]
);
```

See the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-inputs) for more info.

**Update**

If you're experiencing issues with `find('list')` it is perhaps because your model's `displayField` is not getting set correctly. Cake normally determines the `displayField` for the model on initialisation. If this isn't working, or you want a different field you can set this manually in the model's `initialize()` method. *E.g.*:-

```
class MagazinesTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->displayField('name');
    }
}
```

Changing `'name'` to the appropriate field.

Alternatively, you can choose which field Cake will use for the values returned by `find('list')` (this is particularly useful when you want to override the default `displayField`). *E.g.*:-

```
$this->Issues->Magazines->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'name'
]);
```

Comment: thanks @drmonkeyninja, there is something that i'm missing or i'm not explaining well, because what i get with this is an input select populated with the key (magazine.id) instead the value (magazine.name)

Comment: @RaulMagdalenaCatala what does your `$magazines` variable look like? If you call `debug($this->Issues->Magazines->find('list')->toArray())` in your controller do you see an array of magazine names indexed by their IDs? Perhaps your Magazines model is not correctly setup?

Comment: no, this is wat i get: [
 (int) 1 => (int) 1,
 (int) 2 => (int) 2,
 (int) 4 => (int) 4
]

Comment: @RaulMagdalenaCatala sounds like the `displayField` isn't getting set correctly. I've updated my answer with two options that should resolve the problem.

Comment: i've updated also my question to try to make it clear. i have updated my MagazinesTable with the displayField set to 'name' but i have the same result, the magazine.id instead of magazine.name. thanks for your patience.

Comment: just fixed, i was updating my IssuesTable displayField instead of MagazinesTable. really thanks

Comment: `$this->Issues->Magazines->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'name'
]);` That was what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Display selected option in month helper**

```
$this->Form->month('students.month', [
'label' => false, 
'value'=>date('m'),
'required'=>true
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually helped me.

```
$this->Issues->Magazines->find('list', [
   'keyField' => 'id',
   'valueField' => 'name'
]);
```