# HOW TO DISPLAY DATA IN DROP DOWN LIST FROM OTHER TABLE IN CAKEPHP 3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables:

> departamento (spanish of "region")
>  
>   provincia (spanish of "province")

"departamento" have three fields:

> id_departamento 
>  departamento (name of region) 
>  presidente (governor)

"provincia" have four fields:

> id_provincia 
>  id_departamento (foreign key) 
>  provincia (name of province)
>  gobernador (governor)

I generate cakephp code with command lines (models, controllers and templates).

but, in the generated view, show insert input id, and i don't want it --> 
[SCREEN CAPTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNGwu.jpg)

When i'm going to add a new province, i would like to display and replace the region id field by the **name of region** like drop down list

**PROVINCIACONTROLLER.PHP**

> ```
> <?php
> namespace App\Controller;
>
> use App\Controller\AppController;
>
> /**
>  * Provincia Controller
>  *
>  * @property \App\Model\Table\ProvinciaTable $Provincia
>  */
> class ProvinciaController extends AppController
> {
>
>     /**
>      * Index method
>      *
>      * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
>      */
>     public function index()
>     {
>         $provincia = $this->paginate($this->Provincia);
>
>         $this->set(compact('provincia'));
>         $this->set('_serialize', ['provincia']);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * View method
>      *
>      * @param string|null $id Provincium id.
>      * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
>      * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
>      */
>     public function view($id = null)
>     {
>         $provincium = $this->Provincia->get($id, [
>             'contain' => []
>         ]);
>
>         $this->set('provincium', $provincium);
>         $this->set('_serialize', ['provincium']);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Add method
>      *
>      * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
>      */
>     public function add()
>     {
>         $provincium = $this->Provincia->newEntity();
>         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
>             $provincium = $this->Provincia->patchEntity($provincium, $this->request->data);
>             if ($this->Provincia->save($provincium)) {
>                 $this->Flash->success(__('The provincium has been saved.'));
>
>                 return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
>             } else {
>                 $this->Flash->error(__('The provincium could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
>             }
>         }
>         $this->set(compact('provincium'));
>         $this->set('_serialize', ['provincium']);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Edit method
>      *
>      * @param string|null $id Provincium id.
>      * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
>      * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
>      */
>     public function edit($id = null)
>     {
>         $provincium = $this->Provincia->get($id, [
>             'contain' => []
>         ]);
>         if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
>             $provincium = $this->Provincia->patchEntity($provincium, $this->request->data);
>             if ($this->Provincia->save($provincium)) {
>                 $this->Flash->success(__('The provincium has been saved.'));
>
>                 return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
>             } else {
>                 $this->Flash->error(__('The provincium could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
>             }
>         }
>         $this->set(compact('provincium'));
>         $this->set('_serialize', ['provincium']);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Delete method
>      *
>      * @param string|null $id Provincium id.
>      * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
>      * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
>      */
>     public function delete($id = null)
>     {
>         $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
>         $provincium = $this->Provincia->get($id);
>         if ($this->Provincia->delete($provincium)) {
>             $this->Flash->success(__('The provincium has been deleted.'));
>         } else {
>             $this->Flash->error(__('The provincium could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
>         }
>
>         return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
>     }
> }
> ```

**PROVINCIATABLE.PHP**

> ```
> <?php
> namespace App\Model\Table;
>
> use Cake\ORM\Query;
> use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
> use Cake\ORM\Table;
> use Cake\Validation\Validator;
>
> /**
>  * Provincia Model
>  *
>  * @method \App\Model\Entity\Provincium get($primaryKey, $options = [])
>  * @method \App\Model\Entity\Provincium newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
>  * @method \App\Model\Entity\Provincium[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
>  * @method \App\Model\Entity\Provincium|bool save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
>  * @method \App\Model\Entity\Provincium patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data,
> ```
>
> array $options = [])
>        * @method \App\Model\Entity\Provincium[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
>        * @method \App\Model\Entity\Provincium findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null)
>        */
>       class ProvinciaTable extends Table
>       {
>
> ```
>     /**
>      * Initialize method
>      *
>      * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function initialize(array $config)
>     {
>         parent::initialize($config);
>
>         $this->table('provincia');
>         $this->displayField('id_provincia');
>         $this->primaryKey('id_provincia');
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Default validation rules.
>      *
>      * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
>      * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
>      */
>     public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
>     {
>         $validator
>             ->integer('id_provincia')
>             ->allowEmpty('id_provincia', 'create')
>             ->add('id_provincia', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);
>
>         $validator
>             ->integer('id_departamento')
>             ->requirePresence('id_departamento', 'create')
>             ->notEmpty('id_departamento');
>
>         $validator
>             ->requirePresence('provincia', 'create')
>             ->notEmpty('provincia');
>
>         $validator
>             ->requirePresence('gobernador', 'create')
>             ->notEmpty('gobernador');
>
>         return $validator;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
>      * application integrity.
>      *
>      * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
>      * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
>      */
>     public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
>     {
>         $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['id_provincia']));
>
>         return $rules;
>     }
> }
> ```

**PROVINCIA.PHP**

> ```
> <?php
> namespace App\Model\Entity;
>
> use Cake\ORM\Entity;
>
> /**
>  * Provincium Entity
>  *
>  * @property int $id_provincia
>  * @property int $id_departamento
>  * @property string $provincia
>  * @property string $gobernador
>  */
> class Provincium extends Entity
> {
>
>     /**
>      * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
>      *
>      * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
>      * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
>      * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
>      *
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $_accessible = [
>         '*' => true,
>         'id_provincia' => false
>     ];
> }
> ```

ADD.CTP (ADD PROVINCE)

> ```
> <nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
>     <ul class="side-nav">
>         <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
>         <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Provincia'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
>     </ul>
> </nav>
> <div class="provincia form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
>     <?= $this->Form->create($provincium) ?>
>     <fieldset>
>         <legend><?= __('Add Provincium') ?></legend>
>         <?php
>             echo $this->Form->input('id_departamento');
>             echo $this->Form->input('provincia');
>             echo $this->Form->input('gobernador');
>         ?>
>     </fieldset>
>     <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
>     <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
> </div>
> ```

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: Please, disable CAPS

Comment: You mean you want a drop down which would populate values from "DEPARTAMENTO" table? With value ID_DEPARTAMENTO 
 and text DEPARTAMENTO (NAME OF REGION)?..Please disable caps and mention properly the name of your table and model.

Comment: I want the view, I want a drop down list showing values of names of region, but, in the insert query on database, the row insert with the "id_departamento" of the name of region, because table "provincia" has "id_departamento" as foreing key references epartamento(id_departamento)...

Comment: my question is similar to this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947323/cakephp-3-0-how-to-populate-a-select-field-with-values-instead-of-id

Answer (score 0):

> If you want a drop down list of **departmento**, you need to fetch them using [find('list')](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs) and **set** it to the template.

Considering your table name is Departmento, and you want to populate value id_departamento and text departamento, try the following:

```
/* Controller Code */
public function add()
{
    $provincium = $this->Provincia->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       /* Other code */
    }
    /* Modified code starts */
    $departmento = $this->Departmento->find('list', [
        'keyField'   => 'id_departamento',
        'valueField' => 'departmento'
    ]);
    $this->set(compact('departmento'));
    /* Modified code ends*/
    $this->set(compact('provincium'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['provincium']);
}

/* Template code */

 echo $this->Form->select('id_departamento', $departmento, [
     'empty' => 'Departmento'
 ]);
```

Comment: yes, it's "departamento" (region in english = departamento in spanish)..

Comment: Depending on your model/table fields names, you might have to do a bit of modifications. But overall, this is the idea you need to follow to get what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes. I want the view, I want a drop down list showing values of names of region (table "departamento", field "departamento" or (name)), but, in the insert query on database, the row insert with the "id_departamento" of the name of region, because table "provincia" have "id_departamento" as foreing key references departamento(id_departamento)... sorry by my bad english writting...